# Custom SSH From USB

Tags: git, ssh

I have a project I'm working on from a USB plugged into a public computer.  I'm looking to set up a custom SSH profile from this USB specifically (i.e., not changing SSH config in the user's home directory).  I'd prefer to have an SSH config file in my working directory on the USB, but I don't know if that's possible.

(btw, my overall purpose is to setup custom ssh options for the git repo in the project's working directory)

Answer (score 1):

I trust you know about

```
ssh -F /path/to/USB/worktree/ssh_config
```

So you could exploit that, e.g.

```
alias ssh=`ssh -F /path/to/USB/worktree/ssh_config`
```

in your interactive shell.

Note, however, that you can already set repo specific options like e.g.

```
  ; Proxy settings
  [core]
          gitproxy="ssh" for kernel.org
          gitproxy="ssh -i ../some_pubkeyfile" for our_shared_repo.our_company.dk
          gitproxy=default-proxy ; for all the rest
```

Not only can you set it for certains hosts, you can also configure it with the `.git/config` per working tree.

Comment: Thank you so much!  How does gitproxy work exactly?  Should I be able to specify custom ssh commands for certain remotes?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't used gitproxy settings myself. But it jumped at me when searching `man git-config` for `ssh`